# Batch perform action on all files in dir - wrong variable value?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to convert a folder of SWFs to images using swftools.
The actual conversion is working fine, however I'm having issues trying to get it to run for all files in a folder. (and would be nice to get it to work for all subfolders as well).

Let's say the folder contains the following files: 1.swf, 2.swf, ...
Now the script I wrote for this is:

```
for %i in (*.swf) do (
set fileName=%i
swfrender "%fileName%" -o "%fileName:~0,-4%.png"
)
```

Which I'm running from inside the folder containing the SWF files. However rather than the expected result I'm seeing the following in my command prompt:

> set fileName=1.swf  swfrender "3.swf" -o "3.png" )
>
> set fileName=2.swf  swfrender "3.swf" -o "3.png" )

Now from what I could find the script should be fine, so I have no clue what's going wrong.

Oddly enough the following does seem to work:

```
for /R %x in (*.swf) do swfrender %x -o %x.png
```

But I'd rather not have to rename a couple of hundred files to remove the redundant .swf portion from the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (and in batch files you need doubled `%` for the loops tokens):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (*.swf) do (
  set fileName=%%i
  swfrender "!fileName!" -o "!fileName:~0,-4!.png"
)
```

or you can extract the file name without extension:

```
for %%i in (*.swf) do (
  swfrender "%%~i" -o "%%~ni.png"
)
```

Comment: Both seem to lead to: bla\swfFolder>for %%i in (*.swf) do (
%%i was unexpected at this time.

If I try it with %i rather than %%i it looks like its using the !fileName! like that rather than the relevant value despite delay expansion being enabled.

Comment: @JoeDaenens - if you run this from command line you'll need to use single `%`. If it is in a batch file it needs to be doubled.

Comment: +1 for avoiding delayed expansion in your second approach! However, you do not need the interim variable `fileName`.

Comment: @aschipfl - yes forgot to delete the line